# alexa response is invalid/rest call trouble

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong with my lambda function for a few days. I suspect its the rest call but I can't figure out why alexa isn't taking the output. I've added some more console.logs and it seems like its never leaving the TrashPickUpIntent. Here is the code:

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const https = require('https');


var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('SayHello');
    },
    'HelloWorldIntent': function () {
        this.emit('SayHello')
    },
    'TrashPickUpIntent' : function () {
        console.log("inside trash pick up intent");
        this.emit('trashPickUp');
    },
    'SayHello': function () {
        console.log("testing here");
        this.emit(':tell', 'Hello there!');
    }, 
    'TrashPickUp': function () {
        var TrashPickUp="Trash Pick up on ";
        var Recycling="Recycling on ";
        var AlexaTell="For Address ";
        var output ="test";
        console.log("inside trash function");
        //Get data for Tash PickUp and Recycling
        https.get('https://data.boston.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=fee8ee07-b8b5-4ee5-b540-5162590ba5c1&q={"Address":"866 Huntington ave"}', (res) => {
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers:', res.headers);

            //Get Response and parse String for Alexa
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                output += d;
            });

            res.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e);
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                var apiResponse = JSON.parse(output);
                output = AlexaTell + apiResponse["result"]["records"][0]["Address"] + 
                TrashPickUp + apiResponse["result"]["records"][0]["Trash"] +
                Recycling + apiResponse["result"]["records"][0]["Recycling"];
                console.log(output);
            });
        });
        console.log("outside about to send output");
        this.emit(':tell', output);                        
    }
};

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

my rest/js knowledge is weak and my alexa knowledge even weaker. I suspected it had something to do with the async call within https.get, so I moved "this.emit" into the on end call. Then I tried using "var self = this" just above the get call, because I had read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43151661/3029807) that perhaps my this reference wasn't accessible within the get call.

none of this has solved my issue. When I test it through the skill kit it says the "response is invalid", when I test it with the input from the voice test and input it directly into a lambda test it says succeeded with a null result.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Please update question with error from CloudWatch.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue has to do with you exiting the function before the https response resolves by having the line:

```
this.emit(':tell', output);
```

You need to move that into

```
res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('In End: ', output)
    var apiResponse = JSON.parse(output);
    output = AlexaTell + apiResponse["result"]["records"][0]["Address"] + 
    TrashPickUp + apiResponse["result"]["records"][0]["Trash"] +
    Recycling + apiResponse["result"]["records"][0]["Recycling"];
    console.log(output);
    this.emit(':tell', output);  
});
```

You will also need to change the line

```
var output ="test";
```

to

```
var output ="";
```

Otherwise your response will have "test" at the beginning.

This will fix your issue since now you are emitting your response to Alexa in the callback of the get call instead of outside of it. Lambdas don't support concurrent calls so once the main thread ends the lambda will close. You should always emit your response in a callback rather than asynchronously.

Comment: turns out it was a misspelling from the start.